# Django/Selenium: Very simple functional test hangs because of tearDown()

Tags: python, django, selenium, functional-testing

I've got a very simple test going on

```
class NewVisitorTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()

    def test_can_see_homepage(self):
        self.browser.get('http://localhost:8000')
        self.assertIn('Floppers', self.browser.title)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(warnings='ignore')
```

This test runs completely it seems (the browser opens and closes) but the test hangs and never actually finishes. On the other hand, if I comment out the `teardown()` method, it runs fine (but I have to manually close the browser). If I run in verbose mode, it looks like the test is hanging on the `test_can_see_homepage` test.

```
Adding permission 'Permission object (None)'
Adding permission 'Permission object (None)'
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
test_root_url_resolves_to_splash__view (main.tests.unit.test_splash.SplashPage) ... ok
test_can_see_homepage (main.tests.functional.test_splash.NewVisitorTest) ...
```

It'll stay like this indefinitely. If I `ctrl + c` out of it, then it shows me the results as if it finished. What might be going on here, that having a `tearDown()` method causes the test itself to stall?

If it's relevant, I'm using Arch Linux w/ Awesome-WM (in case there's a signal that's not being sent due to my setup or something).

Comment: Does `self.browser.close()` do the same thing (I would expect it to, but worth checking)?

Comment: @WillKeeling It does, yeah. :(

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the geckodriver? https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.23.0

Comment: @WillKeeling I am. I've placed it in the `env/bin/` folder in my virtual environment, but that didn't change anything. I also looked through the `geckodriver.log` files and didn't see much in the way of a hint